# Dismiss DialogFragment after screen rotation

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I have a problem with dismissing an DialogFragment after the screen was rotated.

The DialogFragement is created like this:

```
CalendarDialog calendar = new CalendarDialog();
calendar.setOnCalendarEventClickListener(this);
dialog = calendar;
calendar.show(getFragmentManager(), "calendar");
```

and the Listener looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCalenderEventClick(CalendarEvent event) {
    // TODO crashing after rotating while in dialog
    ((DialogFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("calendar")).dismiss();
    // dialog.dismiss();
    showDay(event.getBegin());
}
```

When just calling the Listener everything is working.
But when the screen was rotated the dismiss gets a NullPointerException (both solutions above).

I've also tried to save and restore the dialog id without success:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putLong("dialog", dialog.getId());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState,
        PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null)
        return;
    dialog = (DialogFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(savedInstanceState.getInt("dialog"));
    // super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
}
```

Apparently the activity gets recreate at rotate so everything is gone...

Comment: As for a dialog, you could use `setRetainInstance(true)` in your `CalendarDialog`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean)

Comment: Ok, not crashing any more but it disappears right after (or while) rotating. So the error is gone but it's also not what i wanted.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that when the orientation changes, `onCreate` method is called again and view is recreated, try adding this to your manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

if your using more configChanges just add a "|"

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: I already know this "solution" but i think thats no solution only a workaround. The user has to pay for the clueless programmer - thats not my opinion development should work...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And I found the only one solution. With using Otto and events. For example:
MyDialogFragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    BusProvider.getInstance().unregister(this);
}

@Subscribe
public void OnDismissLoadingDialogEvent(DismissLoadingDialogEvent event) {
    dismissAllowingStateLoss(); // Allowed here without consequences
}
```

And in activity:

```
loadingDialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),       LoadingDialogFragment.class.getName());
```

and for dismissing:

```
BusProvider.getInstance().post(new DismissLoadingDialogEvent());
```

It is not elegant solution, but it works properly.